# Angular 2 front-end + Spring boot back-end on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am not 100% sure I am asking this on the right platform, please let me know if it is not.

Right now I am using Angular 2 for front-end and Spring Boot for back-end. I would like to know what would be the most optimal way to use the Google Cloud platform with my current set-up. So my front-end is Angular 2 (CLI) and back-end Java.

I was thinking to run my back-end and front-end on two seperate App Engines.

Comment: Your front-end is nodejs? How exactly would that work?

Comment: @NexusDuck Woops, no. My front-end is Angular 2 CLI.

Comment: Don't see why you wouldn't be able to run your backend and frontend on 1 app engine project. App engine is able to serve static files (your frontend files) as well

Comment: And I can run yarn/npm on an App Engine project?

Comment: Off course you can use npm, app engine will just serve your html/js/css like any other webserver.